# What is the best way to implement a dividend paying contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens

Every block `x` amount of ether is put into the smart contract - Where `x` is variable.

And a user with a token balance of `y` is entitled to `y / total token supply` of the total dividends in the smart contract.

What is the best way to implement such a thing?

Comment: see ERC2222 and its example impl https://github.com/atpar/funds-distribution-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single “best” way to do this, while there are several common ways.  Here is one of them:

```solidity
contract DividendToken {
    uint private totalDividendsPerToken = 0;
    mapping (address => uint) private dividendsPerTokenPaid;

    function distributeDividends () public payable {
        require (msg.value % totalSupply () == 0);
        totalDividendsPerToken += msg.value / totalSupply ();
    }

    function payOutDividends (address payable who) internal {
        uint amount =
            balanceOf (who) *
            (totalDividendsPerToken - dividendsPerTokenPaid [who]);
        dividendsPerTokenPaid [who] = totalDividendsPerToken;
        who.transfer (amount);
    }

    ...
}
```

Function `payOutDividends` should be called for an address prior to any change of token balance for this address, i.e. in functions such as `transfer`, `transferFrom`, `mint`, `burn` etc. like this:

```solidity
function transfer (address to, uint value) public returns (bool) {
    payOutDividends (msg.sender);
    payOutDividends (to);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a place where the reasoning for the formula is explained more clearly? I can't find an intuitive reason for the reason why it's calculated the way it is.

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of the require check inside of distributeDividends?

Comment: To ensure that the total amount of dividends divides by the total number of tokens without reminder.  Otherwise it would be impossible to distribute it evenly.